# Infer types of template template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, reflection

I need to deduce the typenames of a parameter template. Those parameters would then be used with reflection to achieve my goal. So far I have come up with the following which seems to work:

```
template <typename... F, typename T>
static void templateA(T t) {
/* Use reflection to obtain the types in F */
}
```

Which would then be called like this:

```
template <typename T>
void templateB() {
/* Do some work */
}

templateA<float>(templateB<float>);
```

This works but I was wondering if it is possible to infer the types of template B from F? I'm trying template template parameters but so far it's not working. Something like this:

```
template <typename... F, template<typename V> class T>
static void templateA(T<F...> t) {
/* Use reflection to obtain the types in F */
}

templateA<float>(templateB);
```

Is this possible. I understand this is a bit confusing use case but would appreciate any tips on how to achieve this.

Comment: What is `templateB`? A variable template?

Comment: templateB is a function template. I edited the question with an example

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve?  C++ doesn't have reflection.

Comment: Not possible. To pass something as a function parameter, it has to have a type, but function templates don't have one until you specify template arguments for them. Template lambdas can be passed like this though.

Comment: @NathanOliver the problem that I'm trying to solve is that, depending on some configuration variable, I need to either call templateB directly or call a function that expects a string with "templateB<float>" as argument.